# Creating a method in a class to update a list held within the class

Tags: c#, list, class, methods

I'm trying to create a list in a class named 'Advisers' that would hold a list of students who are advised by 1 instance of an adviser. I have a student class created, and have no trouble there, but I get errors in my adviser class on runtime.

```
class Advisers
{
    private string _Fname;
    private string _Lname;
    private string _Department;
    private List<Student> _StudentsAdvised;   

    //constructor
    public Advisers()
    {
        _Fname = "";
        _Lname = "";
        _Department = "";
        _StudentsAdvised = null;
    }

    public void AddToList(Student newStudent)
    {
        _StudentsAdvised.Add(newStudent);
    }

    public List<Student> StudentsAdvised
    {
        get { return _StudentsAdvised; }
        set { _StudentsAdvised = value; }
    }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _Fname; }
        set { _Fname = value; }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get { return _Lname; }
        set { _Lname = value; }
    }

    public string Department
    {
        get { return _Department; }
        set { _Department = value; }
    }       
}
```

The `AddToList` method is what I call in the main form to add an instance of a student to the `StudentsAdvised` list held in the Adviser class.

```
private void stuAssignAdviBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int stuIndex = stuLstbox.SelectedIndex;
        int advIndex = adviListBox.SelectedIndex;

        if (stuLstbox.SelectedIndex != -1 && adviListBox.SelectedIndex != -1)
        {
            string AdvLastName = AdviserList[advIndex].LastName;
            StudentList[stuIndex].AdviserLastName = AdvLastName;


            AdviserList[advIndex].AddToList(StudentList[stuIndex]);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Select 1 student and 1 adviser.");
        }
    }
```

The error messages comes up in the Adviser class here:

```
public void AddToList(Student newStudent)
{
    _StudentsAdvised.Add(newStudent);
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: wouln't they be advisees?

Comment: change _StudentsAdvised = null; in your constructor to _StudentsAdvised = new List<Student>();

Comment: the List could be BindingList...at least...or derive a class from bindinglist<Student>(or a generic one) with the proper implementations you need then in your adviser class use that derived from bindinglist class to hold the information...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont see you initializing your `List<Student> _StudentsAdvised` anywhere

you *could* do that in the class constructor

```
//constructor
public Advisers()
{
    _Fname = "";
    _Lname = "";
    _Department = "";
    _StudentsAdvised = new List<Student>();
}
```

Comment: agreed - you are NOT newing up your collection in the constructor. you are just making it null thus throws a nullReferenceException when you try to use that object

Comment: My (noob) understanding of the constructor was that it initializes the values. I wanted to start the list empty, which is why I set it to null. This worked though, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

erm,

```
public class Advisess : List<Student>
{
    private readonly Advisor advisor;

    private Advisess()
    {
    }

    public (IEnumerable<Student> adivsees, Advisor advisor)
        : base(advisees)
    {
        this.advisor = advisor;
    }

    public (Advisor advisor)
    {
        this.advisor = advisor;
    }

    public Advisor Advisor
    {
        get
        {
            return this.advisor;
        }
    }
}
```